# What am I doing wrong with replaceChild()?

Tags: javascript

I am really having trouble with this replaceChild() function. I am trying to teach myself javascript. Thank god I learned Object Oriented basics from java or I will be completely lost. Can This code is supposed to be replacing one picture with another. It's not replacing the picture at all. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? I will really appreciate it.

```
<html>
<body>

<script type = "text/javascript">

function isImage(y){
// used to embed images 
var peter = document.createElement("img");
peter.width = y;
peter.height = "600";
peter.src = "site.jpg";
document.body.appendChild(peter);
}


function secondImage(x){
var peterII = document.createElement("img");
peterII.width = x;
peterII.height = "600";
peterII.src = "home.png";
document.body.replaceChild(peterII,peter);
}

//function listener 

function addListeners1(){

// adds eventlistener to the button listed at the bottom
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener("click",btntwo);
document.getElementById('mybuttonII').addEventListener("click",btnthree);
}

function btntwo(){
isImage(400);
}


function btnthree(){
secondImage(400);
}


// adds listener when the window is loaded
onload = addListeners1;
//onload = isImage(400);

</script>

<! adds buttons>
<button id="mybutton" style="width:100;height:50" value = "clickhere">MyButton</button>
<button id="mybuttonII" style="width:100;height:50">MyButtonII</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The variable `peter` is local to the scope of `isImage()`.

Comment: You should have noticed a ReferenceError in `secondImage` when it tried to reference the undefined variable `peter`. Were you watching the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code

```js
var peter;

function isImage(y){
// used to embed images 
peter = document.createElement("img");
peter.width = y;
peter.height = "600";
peter.src = "http://www.gettyimages.com/CMS/Pages/ImageCollection/StaticContent/image5_170127819.jpg";
document.body.appendChild(peter);
}


function secondImage(x){
var peterII = document.createElement("img");
peterII.width = x;
peterII.height = "600";
peterII.src = "http://www.studiotv.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Klimas-website-edited.jpg";

document.body.replaceChild(peterII,peter);
}

//function listener 

function addListeners1(){

// adds eventlistener to the button listed at the bottom
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener("click",btntwo);
document.getElementById('mybuttonII').addEventListener("click",btnthree);
}

function btntwo(){
isImage(400);
}
function btnthree(){
secondImage(400);
}
addListeners1();
```

```html
<! adds buttons>
<button id="mybutton" style="width:100;height:50" value = "clickhere">MyButton</button>
<button id="mybuttonII" style="width:100;height:50">MyButtonII</button>
```